# Outlook keeps forgetting safe sender domains and ignoring contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I get a large number of quite similar emails from a particular address, most of which Outlook 2010 identifies as spam. None of these are actually spam. I have Outlook's junk email proection set to Low, and have told it to trust email from my contacts. I have added the address to my list of safe senders, and I have also tried adding it to my contacts.

However: it keeps dropping the address from my safe senders list - I add it, it stays there for a while, but eventually I'll have a legitimate mail identified as spam, and the address will have been dropped from the list. Meanwhile, despite adding that sender to my contacts, it is still classifying their mail as junk.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said that despite of filtering emails from spam, the email client still categorizing it as junk. Follow these some hacks to resolve this error.

1. Inside your spam blocker settings may be you have enabled "**Delete
   Known spam immediately**" turned on. In this case turn off this
   setting immediately.
2. Or when you get any message you can right click on the email and
   select "**This is not a spam**" also.
3. And if the issue persist then better for you to **turn off** the
   **SpamBlocker level**.

**Hope your issue will get resolved soon.**

**Thanks & Regards**

**Sandra**